# Mutation to create a GIST

Tags: graphql, github-graphql, graphql-mutation

I want to create a gist using GitHub's GraphQL API. Although, I couldn't find the mutation to use.

I tried searching for a mutation in the docs but there was none matching `addGist`.
[image]

Is there still a way to make a POST request to create a gist using GraphQL or will I need to resort to using many [GitHub's API endpoints](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/)?